# Losing Excel In-Cell Alignment when Importing to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

We have a number of large Google Sheets that we want to import into a MySQL database.

We're very familir with the process and have done dozens of successful imports.

In this case, however, we are stumped.

The originator of the Google Sheets (I am told) used Excel Align to Center to make the content across the row line up correctly. The data ONLY makes sense if you can read across the rows and see the data aligned horizontally.

We can't find a way to preserve this in-cell alignment after importing to MySQL via pHp and a CSV file of the Google Sheet data.

The data in Sheets looks like this:

[image: Sheet Data Showing Data Aligned to Center]
[image]

When we insert the CSV file to MySQL the result is this

[image: MySQL rendering off same data as above]

We have 45000 entries like this so recoding the originals is not something we want to do.

Is there a programmatic solution?

Thanks

Comment: CSV doesn't support any form of "in cell" formatting, because it stores only the raw data, ad has no concept of format at all.... nor does MySQL (or any other relational database for that matter), which is also simply a data store, with no concept of formatting.... MS Excel formatting is proprietary to MS Excel; although you can create similar formatting using html and css when displaying that data in a web browser

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks

Comment: You should not have to read through an sql database to see the data. Instead you should write a script that displays the data - for example in a page in the browser - and format it there so that it displays the way you want it to. From what I can see, a `nl2br()` on the cell contents will already solve most of your problems. And ideally you would split multiple results in multiple rows in different tables so that the data is stored more logically.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. sounds like a task beyond my skill set.

Comment: Just in case someone else has a similar problem, we came up with a solution to this problem. We simply styled the output with: #searchresults tr{
 white-space: pre;
}   To my utter surprise this did the job.